# Simple server to manipulate priority queues

Tags: c++, c++11, queue, stl, server

In a few months I'll work on a C++ project that could span a year or two. I've a strong C background and for the usual reasons I always chose C over C++ (please forgive me). To extend my capabilities and to move from C to some more powerful language, I felt the time has come to take a serious step towards C++. In order to do so I have created a small C++ project just for myself.
I often read that C programmers do not use the power C++ and all of its glory has to offer, something I madly tried to avoid. I would like some code reflection, points of improvement and other tips. Any suggestions or enhancements are welcome.

Please note that the code below is *only* to illustrate my C++ programming skills. Although the project will compile (and run) is has no purpose, neither does it really do anything. Just a learning experience...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <stdexcept>

#include "queue.h"

using namespace std;

static list<Queue> listQueue;

void tokenizeCmd(const string &str, vector<string> &tokens, const string &delimiters = " ") {
    string::size_type lastPos = str.find_first_not_of(delimiters, 0);
    string::size_type pos = str.find_first_of(delimiters, lastPos);

    while (string::npos != pos || string::npos != lastPos) {
        tokens.push_back(str.substr(lastPos, pos - lastPos));
        lastPos = str.find_first_not_of(delimiters, pos);
        pos = str.find_first_of(delimiters, lastPos);
    }
}

void processCommand(string strCmd) {
    vector<string> tokens;
    tokenizeCmd(strCmd, tokens);

    if (tokens.empty())
      return;

    try {
        if(tokens.at(0) == "list") {
            cout << "All queues [" << listQueue.size() << "]" << endl;
            for(std::list<Queue>::iterator it = listQueue.begin(); it != listQueue.end(); ++it)
                std::cout << it->GetName() << "\t\tProirity: " << it->GetPriority() << '\n';

        } else if(tokens.at(0) == "add") {
            Queue cA(tokens.at(1));
            if (tokens.size() > 2)
                cA.SetPriority(std::stoi(tokens.at(2)));
            listQueue.push_back(cA);

        } else if(tokens.at(0) == "remove") {
            for(std::list<Queue>::iterator it = listQueue.begin(); it != listQueue.end(); ++it)
                if(it->GetName() == tokens.at(1))
                    listQueue.erase(it++);

        } else if(tokens.at(0) == "update") {
            if (tokens.size() < 3)
                return;

            try {
                for(std::list<Queue>::iterator it = listQueue.begin(); it != listQueue.end(); ++it)
                    if(it->GetName() == tokens.at(1))
                        it->SetPriority(std::stoi(tokens.at(2)));
            } catch (const std::exception &ex) {
                std::cerr << ex.what() << '\n';
            }

        } else if(tokens.at(0) == "help") {
            cout << "Available commands:\n"
                 << "\tadd <name> [priority]\n"
                 << "\tremove <name>\n"
                 << "\tupdate <name> <priority>\n"
                 << "\tlist\n";
        } else if(tokens.at(0) == "quit") {
            exit(0);
        }
    } catch (const std::out_of_range &oor) {
        std::cerr << "Too few arguments for " << tokens.at(0) << '\n';
    }
}

void shell() {
    string strCmd;

    cout << "Switch to interactive shell\n";
    cout << "qsh> ";
    while(std::getline(std::cin, strCmd)) {
      processCommand(strCmd);
      cout << "qsh> ";
    }
}

void usage(char *pchProgram) {
    cout << "Usage: " << pchProgram << '\n'
         << " -h\tShow help\n"
         << " -d\tDaemonize the server (default)\n"
         << " -s\tStart interactive shell\n"
         << " -f\tRun on foreground\n";
}

void initialize() {
    Queue cGeneral("generic");
    cGeneral.SetSystemFlag(true);
    listQueue.push_back(cGeneral);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    /* Create at least one queue */
    initialize();

    if (argc < 2)
        /*TODO daemon */
        cout << "Starting server\n";
    else
        for(int i=1; i<argc; i++)
            if (!strcmp(argv[i], "-s"))
                shell();
            else if (!strcmp(argv[i], "-q"))
                exit(0);
            else
                usage(argv[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

This is only the main source (probably enough). The complete code including the class definition can be found on [Github](https://github.com/yorickdewid/QueueCPP/tree/1ae30727badbe95806eca8e4b21e5c25a2581799).

Comment: are you sure about `if (!strcmp(argv[i], "-s"))` and `else if (!strcmp(argv[i], "-s"))` it looks wrong in logic both conditions are same

Comment: Your right, this has to be replaced by some other letter like Q.

Comment: better to use `switch` rather than if-else if nested statements in `processCommand(string strCmd)`. no need for checking exceptions, token.at() has buildin type-safe for free

Comment: @MORTAL `switch` doesn't work with strings.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I won't talk about the big picture (design), but here are some details where you can enhance your code:

- The "iterator" `for` loop was idiomatic a few years ago:

  ```
  for(std::list<Queue>::iterator it = listQueue.begin(); it != listQueue.end(); ++it)
  ```

  But now we have the awesome range-based `for`:

  ```
  for(auto&& elem: listQueue)
  ```

  It will do almost the same thing, except that all the iterator boilerplate is hidden. Also, it will compute `listQueue.end()` only once, so it could even be faster.
- `tokens.at(0)` can be replaced by `tokens.front()` which could be considered more expressive.
- Also, instead of repeatedly computing `tokens.at(0)`, you could store it once in a variable and compare this variables to the different possible values. I am not sure whether the compiler can automagically do that for you.
- You are using `std::string` but you didn't include the header `<string>`. The header `<string.h>` only imports the C-style string handling functions.
- Generally speaking, when including the headers from the C standard library, try to include `<cxxx>` instead of `<xxx.h>` to be sure that every function is in the namespace `std::`.
- Since you implemented everything in one file, this is OK, but if you ever have to write header files, then, at all cost, [avoid `using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/1364752) in header files to avoid potential name clashes due to global namespace pollution.

Comment: I haven't seen ```for(auto&& elem: listQueue)``` very much around the internet. Is is the new standard? If not, where does it come from?

Comment: @YorickdeWid It comes directly from C++11. The syntax is more or less the same as Java's one. `auto&&` would be long to explain but basically it deduces the type, its `const`ness and its reference qualification.

Comment: I see, and yet 90% of Github still needs to learn this? Looks like a hidden trophy :)

Comment: @YorickdeWid I would say that 80% of Github still need to learn about C++11 and a good 30% need to learn that there is more than `<vector>` and `<iostream>` in the standard library.

Comment: Would have never found such a small improvement myself, and so thanks

Comment: @Morwenn just curious, personally i would have written `for(auto& elem : listQueue)` why the `&&` ?

Comment: @CyberSpock That's why I said it would be long to explain. You can read more about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9162949/1364752). Also, note that there was recently a proposal to make `for (val: sequence)` equivalent to `for (auto&& val: sequence)` because `auto&&` is almost always what you want in a `for` loop.

Answer (score 13):

The lack of curly braces here has a potential for errors:

> ```
> if (argc < 2)
>     /*TODO daemon */
>     cout << "Starting server\n";
> else
>     for(int i=1; i<argc; i++)
>         if (!strcmp(argv[i], "-s"))
>             shell();
>         else if (!strcmp(argv[i], "-s"))
>             exit(0);
>         else
>             usage(argv[0]);
> ```

The `if` statement may execute the output statement, but if you were to put some code on the same line as that comment, it would no longer execute the previous statement.

The `else` and the `for` should *really* have curly braces.  This may confuse others and could still break if changes are made carelessly.

This is what it could look like (using your existing style):

```
if (argc < 2) {
    /*TODO daemon */
    cout << "Starting server\n";
} else {
    for (int i=1; i<argc; i++) {
        if (!strcmp(argv[i], "-s"))
            shell();
        else if (!strcmp(argv[i], "-s"))
            exit(0);
        else
            usage(argv[0]);
    }
}
```

Even the inner `if`/`else` statements should have curly braces, but you get the idea.

I've also noticed a lack of curly braces with your other `for` loops.  Make sure this is applied everywhere to minimize error-prone code.

Related: [curly braces and Apple's SSL bug](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/02/curly-braces/)

Comment: I love how Apple offered a perfect argument for people who don't like unbraced flow control statements :3

Answer (score 7):

I still find your code very C like (not C++ like). If I was going to use a word to describe the difference is that C is very imperative while C++ is more declarative.

Example:

Your code to tokenize the stream is:

```
void tokenizeCmd(const string &str, vector<string> &tokens, const string &delimiters = " ") {
    string::size_type lastPos = str.find_first_not_of(delimiters, 0);
    string::size_type pos = str.find_first_of(delimiters, lastPos);

    while (string::npos != pos || string::npos != lastPos) {
        tokens.push_back(str.substr(lastPos, pos - lastPos));
        lastPos = str.find_first_not_of(delimiters, pos);
        pos = str.find_first_of(delimiters, lastPos);
    }
}
```

I would have done:

```
std::stringstream          tokenStream(str);
std::vector<std::string>   tokens(std::istream_iterator<string>(tokenStream),
                                  std::istream_iterator<string>());
```

Admittedly my plain standard version only supports space as a delimiter, but it is not that hard to add the extra functionality to use other delimiters.

You also have start learning the standard algorithms. If you find yourself looping over a container there is probably an algorithm that will do it for you.

```
        for(std::list<Queue>::iterator it = listQueue.begin(); it != listQueue.end(); ++it)
            if(it->GetName() == tokens.at(1))
                listQueue.erase(it++);

        // Can be expressed more tightly with:

        std::erase(std::remove_if(listQueue.begin(), listQueue.end(),
                                  [&tokens](Queue const& q){return q.GetName() == tokens.at(1}),
                   listQueue.end());

       // The difference here is compleity.
       // The original version is O(n^2) while using algorithms is O(n)
```

I would also like to point out a small bug:

```
            if(it->GetName() == tokens.at(1))
                listQueue.erase(it++);         // it++ here is a bug.

       // Note: the erase works correctly.
       //       also the increment works correctly.

       //       But now `it` points at what would have been the next element.
       //       This could even be `end()`
       //       But the `for(;;it++)` is applied to the end of the loop.
       //       If we are now at end() this is undefined behavior.
       //       If we are not at end() then we have just skipped an element in the
       //       list.
```

You are accessing elements via `at()`. You only do this if you need to check the range, otherwise you should be using `operator[]()` to access the elements.

```
    if(tokens.at(0) == "list") {

    } else if(tokens.at(0) == "add") {

    } else if(tokens.at(0) == "remove") {

    } else if(tokens.at(0) == "update") {

    } else if(tokens.at(0) == "help") {

    }
```

I would probably have tried:

```
    if (tokens.size() == 0) {/* Generate Error */break;}
    if(tokens[0] == "list") {

    } else if(tokens[0] == "add") {

    } else if(tokens[0] == "remove") {

    } else if(tokens[0] == "update") {

    } else if(tokens[0] == "help") {

    }
```

I would have personally used the command pattern:

```
    auto action = actions.find(tokens[0]);
    if (action == actions.end()) {
        action = actions["help"];   // default action if none found.
    }
    action->do(tokens);
```

Global variables!

```
static list<Queue> listQueue;
```

Really don't do that. This should have been your top level object around which you built some methods to manipulate it.

Comment: `tokens(std::istream_iterator<string>(tokenStream)` Beware, most vexing parse.

Comment: `std::erase(std::remove_if` I think using this with a `std::list` is a mistake (it moves the elements unnecessarily). There is [`std::list::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/remove) (which is essentially an `erase_if`, but the names are inconsistent) -- Also, there is no `std::erase` yet, although [there's a proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4273.htm). It would need direct access to the container though.

Answer (score 5):

Don't forget about lambdas!  Lambdas can greatly simplify the design of data structures: you create a `map()` function that takes a lambda, and then most of the operations that need to be done to the data structure can be done by invoking `map()` with different lambdas.  The following code demonstrates some of my favorite C++11 features.

Note that I used the verbose name `apply_to_all()` instead of `map()`:

```
/// This is a demonstration of a few nice C++11 features: auto, the ':'
/// iterator, initializer lists, std::function, and lambda expressions.  In
/// many cases, it's possible to achieve the same effect as I present using
/// even less code, but by being explicit I hope I have made the code and
/// comments easy to follow

#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std; // I'm being lazy here... should explicitly use cout,
                     // endl, function, map, pair, string, and vector


/// wrapped_map_t extends map<string, string>.  We start with a map of
/// key/value pairs, where both the key and value are strings, and we add a
/// new method to it.  The new method, apply_to_all, lets us apply a lambda
/// to (a copy of) every key/value pair that is in the map.
///
/// my claim is that lambdas fundamentally change the art of data structure
/// design.  To support my claim, I will show how this one simple function
/// obviates many public functions that one might want int a data structure
/// (count, print, extract_keys, find_matching_keys, etc).
struct wrapped_map_t : public map<string, string>
{
    /// the apply_to_all function simply iterates through the key/value pairs
    /// of the map, calling lambda(key, value) for each pair.  Strictly
    /// speaking, std::map is a red/black tree, and this will do a pre-order
    /// traversal
    void apply_to_all(function<void(const string, const string)>& lambda)
    {
        // note the use of C++11 'auto' keyword to avoid having to specify
        // the type of the iterator
        for (auto i = begin(), e = end(); i != e; ++i)
            lambda(i->first, i->second);
    }
};

int main()
{
    // declare an instance of the extended map
    wrapped_map_t kvpairs;

    // populate the map with some keys and values.  We're going to use some
    // great C++ magic here: initializer lists.  We don't even have to know
    // the type of the list, but the compiler will deduce that it's something
    // like pair<string,string>[]
    kvpairs.insert({{"donald", "duck"}, {"mickey", "mouse"},
                    {"minnie", "mouse"}, {"bat", "man"},
                    {"super", "man"}, {"milo", "otis"},
                    {"mighty", "mouse"}, {"rocky", "squirrel"},
                    {"bullwinkle", "moose"}});

    // 'func' is a reference to a function that takes two strings as its
    // parameters, and returns nothing.  This is a lot nicer than the old C
    // syntax in use before C++11 (i.e., void (*func)(string, string)).
    function<void(string, string)> func;

    // let's assign a new lambda to func.  the lambda will simply print its
    // parameters
    func = [](string k, string v) { cout << "{" << k << ", " << v << "} "; };
    // now let's apply func to every element in the set.  No need for a
    // "print_in_sorted_key_order" function in our class.  It would be
    // trivial to add "print keys" and "print values" features without
    // changing the data structure... we'd just need to pass different
    // lambdas
    cout << "KVPairs = ";
    kvpairs.apply_to_all(func);
    cout << endl;

    // The last example was pretty boring.  A function pointer could have
    // done that easily.  Now let's pass in a function that has a captured
    // reference to a variable that is local to this function.  In that way,
    // each time the lambda is called, it can access the function 'my_count'
    // that we declare *right here*.  The net result is that we can count the
    // elements in the map, without requiring map to provide a "count()"
    // function.  Note that the parameters to the lambda aren't used, and
    // that's OK.
    int my_count = 0;
    func = [&my_count](string k, string v) { my_count++; };
    kvpairs.apply_to_all(func);
    cout << "Elements in map = " << my_count << endl;

    // OK, so we could have achieved that effect with an apply_to_all that
    // took three parameters: string, string, int&.  But would we really want
    // to do that for every possible pass-by-reference type?  For example,
    // here we pass a vector of strings so that we can copy out all keys from
    // the map
    vector<string> keys;
    func = [&keys](string k, string v) {keys.push_back(k);};
    kvpairs.apply_to_all(func);
    // print the keys, to show that it worked
    cout << "Keys in map = {";
    for (auto i : keys)
        cout << i << ",";
    cout << "}" << endl;

    // note, too, that we can use the lambda to capture multiple local
    // variables, and that some can be pass by value while others are pass by
    // reference.  Here 'pre' is pass by value, 'keys' is pass by reference,
    // and our function copies into 'keys' all keys in the map whose values
    // begin with 'mo'
    string pre = "mo";
    keys.clear();
    func = [&keys, pre](string k, string v) { if (v.find(pre) == 0) keys.push_back(k);};
    kvpairs.apply_to_all(func);
    cout << "Keys whose values start with 'mo' = {";
    for (auto i : keys)
        cout << i << ",";
    cout << "}" << endl;

    // this example is much like the prior one.  Here we extract all
    // key/value pairs where the key begins with 'mi'
    pre = "mi";
    vector<pair<string, string>> pairs;
    func = [&pairs, pre] (string k, string v)
        { if (k.find(pre) == 0) pairs.push_back(make_pair(k, v)); };
    kvpairs.apply_to_all(func);
    cout << "Elements whose key begins with 'mi' = {";
    for (auto i : pairs)
        cout << "{"<<i.first<<", "<<i.second<<"} ";
    cout << "}" << endl;

    // the point of this example is to illustrate that when the lambda is
    // called with the key and value, the function we are executing *cannot*
    // modify the internals of the map.  Put another way, the lambda does not
    // become a member function of the class.  So, for example, if we wanted
    // to add a suffix to every key, then the only way we could do it would
    // be by explicitly updating the k/v pair in the map.
    string suf = " <3";
    // note: we need to capture *kvpairs itself* by reference
    func = [&kvpairs, suf] (string k, string v) { kvpairs[k] = v+suf; };
    kvpairs.apply_to_all(func);
    // use a lambda to print it out
    func = [](string k, string v) { cout << "{" << k << ", " << v << "} "; };
    cout << "Modified kvpairs = ";
    kvpairs.apply_to_all(func);
    cout << endl;
}
```

To compile, using a modern gnu toolchain (4.7 or later), add the "-std=c++11" flag.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to add to all the other excellent answers:

Your usage of `erase()` in `processCommand` is not correct. Once erase has deleted an element the iterator is no longer valid. Instead you should use the iterator that is returned by `erase()`:

```
  for(std::list<Queue>::iterator it = listQueue.begin(); it != listQueue.end(); )
  {
    if (it->GetName() == tokens.at(1))
    {
       it = listQueue.erase(it);
    }
    else
    {
       ++it;
    }
  }
```

Although as somebody else already noted, you should checkout the `<algorithm>` header. When you master algorithms and containers you are going in the right direction learning C++.

The `using namespace std` at the top of the file can be replaced with `using` statements inside the functions which makes the usage clearer. If you write `using namespace std` at the top you risk name collisions or worse in your code .

e.g.

```
void shell()
{
  using std::string;
  using std::cout;
  using std::cin;

  string strCmd;

  cout << "Switch to interactive shell\n";
  cout << "qsh> ";

  while (getline(cin, strCmd))
  {
    processCommand(strCmd);
    cout << "qsh> ";
  }
}
```

Also it is good when you create your own code to place in its own name space, that way you can be a bit more flexible with names and it is also more clear for users of your code where it comes from.

Your code is structured as a C program with normal functions like `initialize()`, `shell()` etc. Instead you should/could put it all into an own class which you create an instance of in your `main()` function.

e.g.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  MyTokenizer myTokenizer(argc, argv);
  return myTokenizer.Run();
}
```

Comment: Note: You are correct about there being a problem with the usage of erase. The problem is not the validity of the iterator (which is valid as it is moved before the erase (it++:  This increments the iterator to the new value (but returns the original value for use in `erase()`. Since we are erasing from a list iterators not pointing at the erased element are unaffected)). Yous solution does solve the problem though.

Comment: Note: `risk name collisions in your code.` this is the least of the problems (and not really a problems because the compiler generating an error message). There are much more serious problems caused by generating erroneous code:http://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/14065

Comment: Nothing wrong with the advice though. So +1

Comment: @LokiAstari good point about calling the wrong function because it provides better match in the link you provided.